# Android Studio Cannot Build gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have got problem when build to Android Studio.
The errors are as follow:

```
> C:\Users\Mehmet Ali
> ?EKER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5c56da03fce8983be0f1e4db139281b1\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_right_mtrl_light.png:
> error: file not found.
> 
> C:\Users\Mehmet Ali
> ?EKER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5c56da03fce8983be0f1e4db139281b1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png:
> error: file not found.
> 
> C:\Users\Mehmet Ali
> ?EKER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5c56da03fce8983be0f1e4db139281b1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png:

> error: file not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following solutions:

1- try to invalidate cache: how? **File** ->  **Invalidate Caches /Restart**

2-Try to change **service directory** path to something without cyrillic symbols, like **"C:/gradle"** in

> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle

And don't forget to invalidate caches after that.

Comment: I tried those but still I have a error. My user name include non-english character

Answer (score 1):

Let's revisit tamtom's answer. Because android studio is not recognizing the directory for non-English characters, you need to move your directory to a different one that only has English characters.

C:/.gradle

sample screenshot of where you need to make the changes:
https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*PhYaqDbqXDRBO0-rILqLeg.png

edit:
I want to comment instead of answer but I need 50 reputation..

Comment: There's one for ya

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have those image files in the `drwaable` folders or remove the reference of those images from your java code.

After that try to `invalidate` the cache.